# What does it mean to have figures included in conference abstract?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, abstract

This is a respected conference. Reviewers accepted but commented this

> Novelty of the topic! Abstract could be better
>   explained and have figures.

Ok, I understand that I need to highlight novelty and more info, but having the figure? what does that mean? Graphical abstract? graph from research results? I am ashamed to ask reviewers because they are well-known names in the field. ( H index over 50 and 30)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the submission guidelines/instructions suggest otherwise, they're not asking for a graphical abstract. They're asking for a figure(s) that illustrate the key results of the presentation (for instance, if your talk is "Correlations between A and B under Conditions X", you could include a graph of a against b).

[Here's an example](https://ep70.eventpilotadmin.com/web/page.php?page=IntHtml&project=ACS17FALL&id=2735880) of a conference abstract with figures, taken entirely at random from the online programme of a recent ACS meeting.

Comment: Thank you, I think you were right, this was chemical conference, but no where inguidlines

Answer (score 1):

This occurs to me as the editors allow authors to put figures in the abstract, or visualize your results using figures.

This might be helpful for those who have limited access to conference proceedings and ease the decision process whether or not to buy the issue.